# Reset only part of the form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reset only a part of my form. This is because, as shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v756xwhc/), I have more then one different "page" of my form shown at different time.

I googled it but i could not find anything useful.

The `reset()` js function resets all the form's input.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You will have to write some js to reset only the inputs inside a specified container

Comment: Set the value to `''` on the reset press for the particular field?

Comment: I want all fields of the shown part of form to reset, not just a particular field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a class to input fields, that should be reset

```
<input type ="text" class="willReset" name = "one">
<input type ="text" class="willReset" name = "two">

$(".reset").on('click',function(){
     $('.willReset').val();
})
```

something like this might help you !!!

Comment: I changed a little bit the code but your answer inspired my solution to this problem. Thanks. Also, why did my answer got downvoted? Any idea?

Comment: your question was not specific.. next time when u ask a question be specific.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to deveolopers world and my knowledge is pretty limited. I probably assume that other people will understand my questions cause of that.